# JWT Validation Failing in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, jwt

I'm trying to configure a React SPA to connect to an Azure API.  JWT validation is failing no matter what I try.  I've been at this for 3 days and at this point am certain that I'm overlooking something easy/obvious.  Here are the details:

- We have two applications:

  - front-end (React)
  - API (Azure API Management)
- Azure Application Gateway sits in front of APIM, but all it does is route traffic (APIM
  is not available from public internet)
- I’ve confirmed that the bearer token is being submitted:
  [image]
- Correct permission scopes are being requested:
  [image]

### API Policy – All Operations:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud">
            <value>guid-of-registered-API-app</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

I’ve tried various other configurations:

- Claim name: **iss**  Claim value: **https://sts.windows.net/*tenant-guid*/**
- Claim name: **appId** Claim value: **api://*guid-of-registered-API-app***
- Claim name: **aud** Claim value: ***aud*-value-of-token-from-jwt.io**
- 2-3 more I don’t recall details on

[see below for decoded token info]

### Permission Scopes

Exposed by registered app: `api://*guid-of-registered-API-app*/user_impersonation`

### API Permissions for Registered App

[image]

### Registered App Authentication

[image]

### Decoded JWT Token

(from JWT.io)

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/tenant-guid/",
  "iat": 1626371934,
  "nbf": 1626371934,
  "exp": 1626375834,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "acrs": [
    "urn:user:registersecurityinfo",
    "urn:microsoft:req1",
    "urn:microsoft:req2",
    "urn:microsoft:req3",
    "c1",
    "c2",
    "c3",
    "c4",
    "c5",
    "c6",
    "c7",
    "c8",
    "c9",
    "c10",
    "c11",
    "c12",
    "c13",
    "c14",
    "c15",
    "c16",
    "c17",
    "c18",
    "c19",
    "c20",
    "c21",
    "c22",
    "c23",
    "c24",
    "c25"
  ],
  "aio": "ASQA2/8TAAAA8QnjnouL0YsWy8XPuXhel67vtgZgYV5CgGbbKZXPsy0=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "app-display-name",
  "appid": " guid-of-registered-API-app",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "family_name": "SMith",
  "given_name": "Joe",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "xxx.x.x.x",
  "name": "Joe Smith",
  "oid": "xxxxxxxx-7bf2-4b4a-b029-2bb10eb41c5e",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "10032000792D2327",
  "rh": "0.AXMA2BYRYPLYhkC01dWK00t0K2OSYmKM4etBkR1sRefhJxVzACg.",
  "scp": "Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email",
  "sub": "YryKYUeWm04s9todeZ32A1-OWhXdLLyWxOgQI-wa6KQ",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": " tenant-guid",
  "unique_name": "joe.smith@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": " joe.smith@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "6mbN5WfQLUCL-LVno3cgAQ",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10",
    "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"
  ],
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "KdgX5DPaGQfoho9O2ohOa_L-ULeYEOnLlTyTX8rf0jE"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1471244337
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but if the issue comes from a wrong validate policy, you may refer to my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171957/15581227) to set up a custom policy to judge the bearer token. If  not, I think you may check if the request has successfully reached apim, e.g. your request didn't append a subscription key while your apim require an subscription key.

Comment: Did you solve this? The issue is that the token is valid but for the wrong **aud** (audience). This can happen when you create the token with the wrong **resource** specified. Note: Your token has the role **Global Administrator**. You should be careful using those credentials. I do not recommend using them for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting scopes for multiple resources in your token request, which is not allowed. According to the [msal example docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md):

```
Access Token requests in MSAL.js are meant to be per-resource-per-scope(s). This means that an Access Token requested for resource A with scope scp1:

- cannot be used for accessing resource A with scope scp2, and,
- cannot be used for accessing resource B of any scope.
```

Instead, in this example, request only the exposed API scope, `api://*guid-of-registered-API-app*/user_impersonation` (i.e., remove `User.Read` and other MS Graph scopes). If you also need to use MS Graph, request a token only for that resource.